# Any customized UI in Master viewcontroller in UISplitViewController is lost in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

As an example, take the Master-Detail Application template project from Xcode, replace the Master UITableViewController with a regular UIViewController and put a label in the center. See images below. In portrait orientation the label appears as expected, but in landscape it is gone. This is not a matter of bad constraints.

[image: landscape with empty contents]
[image: portrait with contents]

If I change the UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode to PrimaryOverlay the label does appear after swiping in landscape.

I first experienced this problem when setting a custom tableview header on the default UITableViewController that is in the template project, so it is not only a problem when using a UIViewController.

Has anyone else experienced this and know a solution?